# If $f|d$, then $f$ is invertible in $R[X]/(d)R[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomial-rings

> Let $R$ be a field and $f$  and $d$ be polynomials in $R[X]$.  If $f|d$, then $f$ is invertible in $R[X]/(d)R[X]$.

I tried to either prove of disprove this statement, but so far I haven't been able to find a counterexample. I was thinking if $f|d$ then for some polynomial $a$ we can write:

$$ a \cdot f= d$$

Now since $d$ is congruent $0$ we can write:

$$ a \cdot f \equiv 0 \pmod{d}$$
 But I don't know how to now deduce that $f$ may or may not be invertible, for invertibility I actually want something like $$a \cdot f =1.$$
I haven't used yet that we are dealing with a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reached $\;a\cdot f=0\;$ , which in fact should be  $\;\overline a\cdot\overline f=\overline 0\;$ (in the quotient ring), you already got a contradiction: since $\;\overline f\;$ is a divisor of zero , it cannot be invertible...

Comment: Of course, elements are either invertible OR zero divisors.

Comment: @WesleyGroupshaveFeelingsToo ... or neither.

Comment: @WesleyGroupshaveFeelingsToo Well, if I understand correctly what you wrote, then no: there can be elements which are neither. For example, in the ring $\;\Bbb Z\;$ , all the non-zero elements which are not $\;\pm1\;$ are neither zero divisors nor invertible...

Comment: what do you mean by "should be" $\bar{a} \cdot \bar{f} = \bar{0}$? Congruence not equality?

Comment: ah, you mean, the representatives, right?

Comment: Yes. So in fact $\;\overline a= a+\langle d\rangle\in R[x]/\langle d\rangle\;$